# Ionic Geofence Plugin is giving errr "ERROR TypeError: Object(...) is not a function at Geofence.initialize "

Tags: cordova, ionic4, geofencing

I am new to ionic . I started to implement ionic geofencing using cordova-plugin-geofence. Please find my app.components file

```
import { Geofence } from '@ionic-native/geofence/ngx';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;
  rootPage: any = HomePage;
  pages: Array<{title: string, component: any}>;

  constructor(
    public platform: Platform, 
    public statusBar: StatusBar, 
    public splashScreen: SplashScreen,

    private geofence: Geofence

    ) {
    this.initializeApp();
    //this.addGeofence();
     // initialize the plugin
     geofence.initialize().then(
      // resolved promise does not return a value
      () => console.log('Geofence Plugin Ready'),
      (err) => console.log(err)
    )

    // used for an example of ngFor and navigation
    this.pages = [
      { title: 'Home', component: HomePage },
      { title: 'List', component: ListPage },
      { title: 'PromotionsList', component: PromotionsListPage }
    ];

  }
```

But if did a 'ionic serve'  can see an error in bowser 'ERROR TypeError: Object(...) is not a function at Geofence.initialize '
    Please help me to solve this issue .
    Ionic version :5. 3. 0